# How to navigate parent frame from child frame

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1

I am facing a very troubling situation during the development of windows phone application. I have a sub frame in my page which navigates through different pages. During these navigations parent frame which is the page remains on its place but the child frame shows different pages.
Now i want to navigate the main frame which is the parent frame from a button inside a child frame.
If I use:

```
Frame.GoBack();
```

It actually navigates the child frame but not the parent. Please help me by letting me know the method of navigating parent frame from a control inside child frame.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can proceed, either try the [VisualTreeHelper](https://github.com/mikoskinen/blog/blob/master/WinRT-XAML-ListView-Autoscroll/WinRT-XAML-ListView-Autoscroll/VisualTreeHelperExtensions.cs) and get the parent of the child frame or store the parent frame in your app.xaml.cs